# Does any GUI diff tool for Linux provides familiar to GitHub layout of differences?

Tags: git, github, git-difftool

Right now I'm using **meld**, but it shows differences only for one file, and if you have few changed files you have to close meld window, then it suggests to open a new window with differences for next file, and so on. Is there any GUI tool that can show differences for all files in one window, somewhat familiar to how it's done in GitHub, for example when you are looking through Pull Request changes, with split mode and stuff?

Comment: Yes meld does that. The problem is git doesn't do that with git-difftool so whatever GUI tool you use cannot (not will not) work with git that way

Comment: `magit` in Emacs does that.

Comment: According to [what is deemed to be on-topic for this website](), "Questions asking us to *recommend* or find a book, *tool*, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource *are off-topic for Stack Overflow* as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call :

```
git difftool -d
```

to invoke your graphical diff viewer, it will open in a "directory diff" mode.

`meld` for example presents you with an overview of all different files, and you can view the differences for each individual file by double clicking.

Comment: I think it might be it